# OpenGL: is there a way to keep only the max value between source and destination?

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, blending

Let's say I have a pixel value of 100 (out of 255, 1 channel) in a framebuffer, and try to write 80 to it.  I would like to keep 100.  But if I try to write 120 to that same pixel, I'd want to write 120 to it.

`dest = max(dest, src)`

Is there a way this can be done in a single pass, perhaps with a blend function or fragment shader method, that's inexpensive enough to be done on a per-triangle basis in a strip of 10K?

Comment: see [Blending](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Blending)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are looking for [glBlendEquation(GL_MAX)](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBlendEquation.xhtml).

Comment: ah, I'm a dummy and assumed `glBlendFunc` was all that was offered, thank you.